# accessing controller in subfolder codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

Just downloaded CI 2.2, renamed the folder to Test1, copied into htdocs folder of xampp.

Tested the site by accessing `http://localhost/Test1`, it launched the Welcome message. Now added a folder to controllers ("admin") and a controller in it (home.php). so the structure is:

```
controllers
    --> admin
          --> home.php
    --> index.php
    --> welcome.php
```

and the code in home.php is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

When I try accessing `http://localhost/Test1/admin/home` or `http://localhost/Test1/admin/home/index` it says object not found (404 error).

I also tried adding `$route['admin'] = "admin/home";` to `application\config\routes.php` so that I can access as `http://localhost/Test1/admin` but of no use. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Did you set base_url in config file.?

Comment: using this $config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/Test1/'; didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a file htaccess.htaccess and past the following code in it.  save it in your Test1 folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /Test1/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Ah, this worked. Any help on the required configuration of htaccess pls?

Comment: so if I have 3 mode folder inside controller then i have to add 3 `RewriteRule` ?  @Tariq

Answer (score 3):

Did you configure CodeIgniter so it can run without the index.php ?
Otherwise the correct url should be something like :

```
http://localhost/index.php/admin/home
```

or

```
   http://localhost/index.php/admin/home/index
```

...witch are pretty much the same for CI.

If you try one of the above url and you have the Welcome message, it's a good news ! And here's the solution : you have to tell CI not to use index.php in your URL.

1. Open your .htaccess or create one in your website root,
2. Put the next lines in it :

   `RewriteEngine on`
   `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)`
   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`
3. Check you've removed the lines you added in the config/routes.php for your tests.
4. Try to access your admin folder with the same URL but without the index.php.

   Tell us what's gong on.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed inputs. After setting the htaccess, it is working fine. However I have marked Tariq's one as answer for his quick response and right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

you should create .htaccess file and paste above mentioned lines. and put that file into you project folder(Test1).